# Communication between Chrome javascript and native Windows code

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ipc

I need to have a communication channel between my web application that runs on Chrome, and a native code on Windows. I need to run a native code when JS requests and pass the results back from native code. The environment is totally managed so I can set trusts and group policies, etc.

I can think of preparing a small web service that runs locally (and allows CORS) and call this service from javascript, but in this case i need to run this code forever.

Any advices will be very helpful. If it is possible i can try Windows registry write/read, pipes, shared memory, MMF or any other way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Chrome [NaCl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) allows a sandboxed C/C++ binary to communicate with client side JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AlexK. But is there any additional runtime requirements for NaCl to run on Chrome? I am asking this, because we have so many terminals, and it would be difficult to add some extensions or do manual modifications. Besides, can "double-sandboxed" NaCl environment communicate to the outside world somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to communicate with local processes without using an extension.  Websockets aren't restricted to communicating with the same domain as the web page, they can communicate with a WebSocket server on localhost.  You have to wrap your native code in a WebSocket server, libraries are available for that though.

Another method is Native Messaging, but it requires a browser extension:

> Native messaging enables a WebExtension to exchange messages with a
>   native application installed on the user's computer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: Is it something for browser extensions to communicate with native applications? Actually i have been looking for a way to exchange messages between javascript and a native app

Comment: Yes that's right, the extension communicates with the native application.  It seems the only way to do it directly, without both communicating via a central (cloud) service.